# Many to many code first not generating an intermediate table in EF6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I am trying to create a many-to-many relation between my User and Request classes. The migration should generate an intermediate table but its generating a one-to-many in both table.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    ...

    public virtual ICollection<Request> Requests{ get; set; }
}

public partial class Request
{
    ...

    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Users{ get; set; }
}

public partial class _12 : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "Request_Id", c => c.Int());
        AddColumn("dbo.Requests", "ApplicationUser_Id", c => c.String(maxLength: 128));
        CreateIndex("dbo.AspNetUsers", "Request_Id");
        CreateIndex("dbo.Requests", "ApplicationUser_Id");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", "Request_Id", "dbo.Requests", "Id");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Requests", "ApplicationUser_Id", "dbo.AspNetUsers", "Id");
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working with he fluent API.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);            

    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .HasMany(t => t.Requests)
                .WithMany(t => t.Users);    
}
```

Giving me this

```
public partial class _12 : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.ApplicationUserRequests",
            c => new
                {
                    ApplicationUser_Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    Request_Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.ApplicationUser_Id, t.Request_Id })
            .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.ApplicationUser_Id, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Requests", t => t.Request_Id, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.ApplicationUser_Id)
            .Index(t => t.Request_Id);

    }
    ...
}
```

I don't have to use the fluent api for table I added myself but the user table is different.